# How many versions of Yajurveda Samhita are there?

Tags: vedas, yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda, krishna-yajurveda

I used to think there are two versions: Shukla and Krishna.

However, I came across many Yajurveda Samhitas (Vajsaneya Samhita, Kathak Samhita, Taittiriya Samhita).

It is very confusing. Exactly, how many Yajurveda Samhitas are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I used to think there are two versions: Shukla and Krishna.`

What you originally thought was correct, wrt the present times. There are two "versions" only, each of which has a further sub-division, many of which you yourself quoted in the question.

Quoting from the government-sponsored [Vedic-heritage](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/samhitas/yajurveda/) site.

#### YAJURVEDA

> ### 1. Nature and Importance:
>
> its character Yajurveda is quite different from the Rigveda & Samaveda
> Samhitas. It is principally in prose form. The word ‘Yajush‘ in the
> Yajurveda is explained variously. But one of its definitions says –
>
> ‘Gadyatmakam yajuh’.
>
> A ‘Yajuh’ is that which is in prose form’. Another definition – ‘Yajur
> Yajateh’ talks about its relation with the sacrifice (Yajna) because
> both the terms are derived from the root. ‘Yaj ‘.
>
> The Yajurveda is more pronouncedly a ritual Veda for it is essentially
> a guide-book for the Adhvaryu priest who had to do practically all
> ritualistic works in a sacrifice. His works vary from the selection of
> a plot of land for the sacrificial altar down to offering oblations to
> the sacred fires. Just as the Samaveda-Samhita is the song-book of the
> Udgata priest, so the Yajurveda-Samhitas are the prayer books for the
> Adhvaryu priest. It is solely meant for the purposes of sacrificial
> rituals.
>
> The Yajurveda is also important for its presentation of philosophical
> doctrines. It preaches the concept of Prana and Manas also. Many
> times, it is quoted for depicting religious and social life of the
> Vedic people. It is also known for giving certain geographical data.
>
> ### 2. Division and Samhitas:
>
> Yajurveda is two-fold-
>
> - The White (or Pure) Yajurveda
> - The Black (or Dark) Yajurveda
>
> The
> Krishna Yajurveda is characterised by mixture of mantra and brahmana
> whereas the Shukla Yajurveda maintains the clear separation of the
> two. The Shukla Yajurveda is related with the Aditya-school and the
> Krishna Yajurveda is related with the Brahma-school. In the beginning
> of his commentary on the Shukla-Yajurveda Samhita, a story is given by
> Mahidhara, about the two-fold division of the Yajurveda. Rishi
> Vaishampayana taught the Yajurveda to Rishi Yajyavalkya and other
> pupils. Once Vaishampayana got angry with Yajyavalkya and asked him to
> give back what he had learnt.
>
> **Yajyavalkya vomited the Veda by the
> power of Yoga, while the other pupils at the command of his teacher
> swallowed up the Yajush thus vomited, assuming the form of birds
> called Tittiri. Thus, the Yajush became dark and was named Kishna or
> Taittiriya.**
>
> **Then Yajyavalkya prayed to the Sun, who came to him in
> the form of a horse i.e. Vaji ) and gave him back the Yajush. Hence
> this Yajurveda was named Shukla or Vajasaneyi.**
>
> #### Sukla (or Vajasaneyi) Yajurveda has two Samhita available today:
>
> - Madhyandina Samhita
> - Kanva Samhtia
>
> #### Krishna Yajurveda has four Samhitas available today:
>
> - Taittiriya Samhita
> - Kathaka Samhita
> - Kapishthala Samhita
> - Maitrayani Samhita
>
> ### 3. Contents :
>
> We find detailed descriptions of sacrifices in the Samhita of
> Yajurveda. The Vajasaneyi-Samhita gives a vivid description of many
> important sacrifices such as – Darsha-purnamasa, Agnihotra, Somayaga,
> Chaturmasya, Agnihotra, Vajapeya, Ashvamedha, Sarva-medha,
> Brahma-yajya, Pitrimedha, Sautramani, and so on. For a general idea
> the contents can be divided into three sections. The first section
> comprises the Darshapurnamasa, the second section deals with the
> Somayaga and the third section comprises the Agnicayanas. The last
> section of the Vajasaneyi-Samhita contains the popular
> Ishavasya-Upanishad. It is important to know that the first eighteen
> Adhyayas of the Vajasaneyi- Samhita are completely given, word for
> word, and explained in the Shatapatha Brahmana of the white Yajurveda.
> On the basis of this point few scholars think that the last sections
> of this Samhita are of a later date.

Comment: How do these Samhitas differ? For example, Madhyandina and Kanva are both Shukla Yajurveda. Then what is the difference? The number of mantras, chapters - what exactly differ between these two sub-versions?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay - check [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22658/what-is-the-speciality-of-madhyandina-shakha)  for instance. You will get some idea how different shakas differ.

Comment: And also this [QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/are-there-any-variants-in-samhita-of-vedas/15445#15445)